# Solr request: SQL-like JOIN, GROUP BY, SUM(), WHERE SUM()

Tags: solr, lucene, request, grouping, solr5

I'm new to Solr and I have the following problem:

I have those documents:

category:contract:

```
{
    "contract_id_s": "contract-ENG-00001",
    "title_s": "contract title",
    "ref_easy_s": "REFAAA",
    "commitment_id_s": "ENG-00001",
},
```

category:commitment:

```
{
    "commitment_id_s": "ENG-00001",
    "title_s": "commitment title",
    "status_s": "Validated",
    "date_changed_status_s": "2015-09-30",
    "date_status_initiated_s": "2015-09-27",
    "date_status_confirmed_s": "2015-09-28",
    "date_status_validated_s": "2015-09-30",
},
```

category:commitment AND sub_category_s:commitment_project:

```
{
    "id": "ENG-00001_AAA",
    "commitment_id_s": "ENG-00001",
    "project_id_s": "AAA",
    "project_name_s": "project name",
    "project_amount_asked_s": "2000",
    "project_amount_validated_s": "2100"
},
{
    "id": "ENG-00001_AAA2",
    "commitment_id_s": "ENG-00001",
    "project_id_s": "AAA",
    "project_name_s": "project name",
    "project_amount_asked_s": "1000",
    "project_amount_validated_s": "1200"
},
```

For each commitment, there could be a contract.
For each commitment, there could be some payments.

Here is what I want to do:
- by default, only select commitment that have at least :
 . one sub_category_s:commitment_project with a project_amount_validated_s value.
 . one contract.
- if filtered on amounts, only select in this list, commitments with the SUM of project_amount_validated_s > amount_min AND < amount_max.

I don't know what is the best practice in terms of performance?
- Requesting the ids of the commitments then requesting the details for them?
- Is there a way to JOIN the contract informations in this request?
- Or the best practice is to request each document one by one?

The problem is that I don't want to request useless data (performance, bandwidth).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've found a solution by using !join.

For instance, in PHP:

```
[
    'q' => "{!join from=id to=service_id score=none}uri:\\$serviceUri* AND -deleted:true",
    'fq' => "{!cache=false}category:monthly_volume AND type:\"$type\" AND timestamp:[$strDateStart TO $strDateEnd]",
    'alt' => 'json',
    'max-results' => 1000,
    'sort' => 'timestamp ASC',
    'statsFields' => 'stats.field=value&stats.facet=timestamp',
]
```

Or with URL request:

http://localhost:8983/solr/fluks-admin/select?q={!join+from=id+to=sector_id+score=none}{!join+from=uri+to=service+score=none}uri:/test-en/service-en*+AND+-deleted:true&fq={!cache=false}category:indicator+AND+timestamp:[201608+TO+201610]+AND+type:("-3"+OR+2+OR+3)+AND+-deleted:true&wt=json&indent=true&json.facet={sum_timestamp:{terms:{limit:-1, field:timestamp, facet:{sum_type:{terms:{limit:-1, field:type, facet:{sum_vol_value:"sum(vol_value)"}}}}}}}

Answer (score 1):

There are some tools available to you in the form of:

- [Solr's Block Join Query Parser](http://yonik.com/solr-4-8-features/) (which allows for simple parent/child
  queries).
- [Solr Facets](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrFacetingOverview) (which allow for aggregrations (e.g. sum of payments) ... [with recent support for faceting on parent/child fields](http://yonik.com/solr-nested-objects/)).
- The Solr Expand Component (which recently [allows parent information to be expanded from a child block join query](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-5285)).

However, I'm not certain you can do everything you're hoping in one query (using with these pieces).  And even if you can, stitching them together doesn't even come close the the simplicity of the `SELECT...JOIN...GROUP BY...HAVING` SQL query you're hoping to replicate.  (Unless you want to try out the [Solr 6 developer snapshot](http://yonik.com/solr-6/) with parallel SQL support)

---

*BUT* If this is your only use-case, *AND* Solr is not your primary datastore, I'd strongly recommend modeling your Solr data to fit your use-case.

E.g. Start simple, denormalize, and only include the fields in your datamodel needed for search:

- Only one type of record:  `commitment`
- Fields

  - `commitment_id_s`
  - `title_s`
  - `status_s`
  - `date_changed_status_s`
  - `date_status_initiated_s`
  - `date_status_confirmed_s`
  - `date_status_validated_s`
  - **`total_payments_asked`** (numeric sum of project_amount_asked from DB)
  - **`total_payments_validated`** (numeric sum of project_amount_validated from DB)
  - **`project_names`** (multiValued list of searchable project names)
  - **`contract_names`** (multiValued list of searchable contract names)

Then your query just needs a filter:

> `total_payments_validated:[`<amount_min>`TO`<amount_max>`]`

to enforce your default criteria.

Once your search has identified the commitment IDs matching the Solr query, then go back and query the source database for any additional information needed for display (project details, contract details, dates, etc...)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll have a look at it thursday!